# MySQL INSERT with SELECT UNION gives syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, insert-into

Supposed I have a table `SomeTable` with a single `INT` column.

This query works fine:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable
(SELECT 1 WHERE true) 
UNION
(SELECT 2 FROM SomeTable WHERE true)
```

[image]

But this gives a syntax error:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable
(SELECT 1 WHERE true) 
UNION
(SELECT 2 WHERE true)
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE true)' at line 4

What's the cause of the error?

How else would I insert multiple rows with a `WHERE` filter?

Comment: Remove the parentheses.

Comment: @jarlh using parentheses with UNION in MySQL is allowed right? Atleast if you reformat the query a bit see [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/83SRH3zxyzrBgMbJ3T4EWm/0)

Comment: When you ask for help with an error, you should include the exact error message.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @GordonLinoff avoid inserting certain rows based on certain conditions (simplified as `true` here).

Comment: @BillKarwin added the error message.

Comment: @jarlh removing parentheses didn't make a difference.

Comment: I suggest that the first query you show above didn't work either, and you didn't notice. Using a `WHERE` clause in a query with no `FROM` clause is always a syntax error.

Comment: @BillKarwin added a gif to prove that it works. MySQL 5.7.25.

Comment: Wacky. I can reproduce that in 5.7, but in 5.6 I get: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE true) 
UNION
(SELECT 2 FROM SomeTable WHERE true)' at line 2`

Answer (score 1):

Remove parentheses and the where clause you have not a FROM clause so your where is not applicable

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable
SELECT 1 
UNION
SELECT 2
```

or if you want a where condition you can use from dual

```
SELECT 1 from dual WHERE true
union 
SELECT 2 from  dual  WHERE true
```

Comment: Why the first query works? It has `WHERE` without `FROM` for the first `SELECT` statement.

Comment: I tried  your first query and don't work  ..  could be you have some issued  local or execute just the second part where   you have from some table in the firts query that ca resulve the union  ..  in the second  not  ..

Comment: Both queries are referring to the same table (which has a single column).

Comment: The insert table don't count  .. the error is in the select  ..  a select without from and with where don't work

Comment: Answer  updated  .. for a valid where condition (using FROM dual)

Comment: The first `SELECT` in the first query has `WHERE` but not `FROM` and it still works.

Comment: I can't reproduce you condition  .. i'm using a mysq 5.7  ..now and  you code don't work .. but using from dual work correctly .. so  if you want a solution  .. the FROM DUAL work .. if your question  is theorical  .. then add  more info about you db enviroment .. so we can try to reproduce your condition

Comment: Using 5.7 too. Try creating a table named `SomeTable` with a single `INT` column.

Comment: Did you try the first (not second) query exactly as it is? What error did it give you?

Comment: I have added a gif to show that the first query works.

Answer (score 0):

Your parenthesis causes the problem. :

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable (col)
     SELECT 1 
     FROM . . 
     WHERE . . .
     UNION
     SELECT 2 
     FROM SomeTable 
     WHERE . . . ;
```

Comment: Why the first query works? Second query fails even with parenthesis removed (no `FROM`).